# How avoid a File created inside an app gets deleted when it get closed

Tags: java, android

I'm making an simple login app in Android Studio, and I dont want to use any data base to store the credentials of the users.
I tried to make an Object File inside the app, and in this storage a HashMap with all the users.
I made that with the following code:

```
File archivo_users = new File("Users.bixa");
    if (!archivo_users.exists()){ 
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream admin = new ObjectOutputStream( openFileOutput(archivo_users.toString(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
            
            HashMap<String, Usuario> admin_user = new HashMap<>();
            // Make an Hash Map with a 'admin' default user
            admin_user.put("admin",new Usuario("admin","admin","admin","admin",'h'));
            admin.writeObject(admin_user);
            admin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"An error ocurred creating Users.bixa",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

After that, I read the file and make an static variable for enter to the data in all the app:

```
try {
            ObjectInputStream baseDatos_usuarios = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(archivo_users.toString()));

            UsuariosRegistrados = (HashMap<String,Usuario>) baseDatos_usuarios.readObject();
            baseDatos_usuarios.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // Muestra ventana emergente en la app con el mensaje de la excepcion
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error al intentar leer la base de Usuarios",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Then, in my register activity, when the user introduce correctly all the data, I update the file this way:

```
BienvenidaActivity.UsuariosRegistrados.put(username,new Usuario(username, contrasenia, nombre, apellido, genero));
                    
                    try {
                        ObjectOutputStream archivo = new ObjectOutputStream( openFileOutput("Usuarios.bixa", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
                        
                        archivo.writeObject(BienvenidaActivity.UsuariosRegistrados);
                        archivo.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"ERROR: No se logro actualizar la base de datos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

All of this works perfectly, but the problem is that when I close the app, the File dosen't conteins the new users, I dont now if the File is deleted when the app is closed or if my conditional of the firts code is wrong and always creates a new file.

Hope someone can help me, and thanks for the time if you read this. Note: Sorry if I wrote something wrong, my native language is spanish.

Comment: `File archivo_users = new File("Users.bixa");` You use this file instance wrong. You should supply a full path. Not only a file name. Very confusing. Use everywhere `openFileOutput("Usuarios.bixa",.... `and never openFileOutput(file.toString(),..

Comment: `archivo_users.exists()` That is impossible code if you only use a file nsme and will always return false.

Comment: So you create every time a new file although it already exists as you use the File class wrong.

Comment: Hi, I'm new creating app for android, where do I should make the file, Inside the "Source" directory of Android Studio? Or what path do I should put inside the File instance. Thanks

Comment: String fileName = "Usuarios.bixa"; File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName); openFileInput(fileName); openFileOutput(fileName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save that file in files directory app-specific storage

```
File file = new File(context.filesDir(),"file.txt");
```

Other apps cannot access to this file